# Custom Post Meta Data in Buddypres Activity Stream

Tags: custom-post-types, buddypress

So I am trying to show a custom post type "Thingy" in the buddypress activity. I am using the code below which displays the activity i.e. when a new custom post type is created and also shows the string "what you need" but as you can see when I call for the get_the_ID(), it simply displays the page ID of the form I am using to publish the post, over that I am sure that the featured images are assigned properly but are not displaying as well.
here is a screenshot:
[image]

This is mainly because I am willing to display featured image, description, title and other data from the post.

Note: I have tried bp_after_activity_add_parse_args as well as bp_before_activity_add_parse_args, gives same result.

I am using buddypress 2.7.2, using pods 2.6.7 for custom post types, Gravity forms to publish the custom posts.

```
 add_post_type_support( 'thingy', 'buddypress-activity' );

 function customize_page_tracking_args() {
// Check if the Activity component is active before using it.
if ( ! bp_is_active( 'activity' ) ) {
    return;
}

bp_activity_set_post_type_tracking_args( 'thingy', array(
    'component_id'             => 'activity',
    'action_id'                => 'new_thingy',
    'bp_activity_admin_filter' => __( 'New Thingy', 'custom-domain' ),
    'bp_activity_front_filter' => __( 'Thingy', 'custom-domain' ),
    'contexts'                 => array( 'activity', 'member' ),
    'bp_activity_new_post'     => __( '%1$s Posted a new <a href="%2$s">Thingy</a>', '' ),
    'position'                 => 100,
) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'customize_page_tracking_args', 1000 );
//record new cpt and enter content for same.
function record_cpt_activity_content( $cpt ) {

if ( 'new_thingy' === $cpt['type'] ) {

    $cpt['content'] = 'what you need'. get_the_ID() . the_post_thumbnail();
}


return $cpt;
}
add_filter('bp_after_activity_add_parse_args', 'record_cpt_activity_content');
```

I would really appreciate any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, found the solution..leaving this here so that it may benefit others.

http://mridulgoswami.com/adding-custom-post-type-to-buddypress-activity-the-right-approach/

Totally step by step solution.

Comment: if possible, create a git repository to that, so that people can contribute to make it better with time.